# Eclipse CDT: Run/debug settings doesn't see system environment variables

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I have a setup where I use my own makefiles to build a c++ project from within eclipse. I kick of eclipse from shell in unix.

I was able to setup the build without a problem because environment variables (inherited from the shell) were listed in build configuration's variable list.

But the run/debug setting seems to be seeing only the native eclipse environment variables - the system environment variables are not included in the variable list I get within the run/debug setting configurations.

What am I missing? I want to run a script before running eclipse to set the an environment variable which eclipse can inherit and use to know the path to the executable. I could pass this to the building configuration, but not to the run/debug config. 
I don't want to put an absolute path because I am part of a development team and I want others who are in different branches/streams to reuse my setup seamlessly.

Comment: There is an `environment` option in the run settings.

Comment: @macroland could you show this?

Comment: @ndarkness, sorry, I switched to VS and have not been using Eclipse for the last 5-6 years.